# getting string is not subtype of RxString in getx flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am building a simple quote app but when I click on getQuote button it gives me following error.

- Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'RxString*

**code**

```
...rest code
 child: Column(
            children: [
              Obx(
                () => Text(
                  quoteController.quote.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 45),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    quoteController.getQuote();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Get Quote"))
            ],
          ),

...rest code
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class QuoteController extends GetxController {
  RxString quote = "".obs;
  getQuote() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.quotable.io/random"));
    quote = jsonDecode(response.body)['content'] as RxString;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting it like this

```
quote.value = jsonDecode(response.body)['content'];
update();
```

Or you can also do this

```
quote("${jsonDecode(response.body)['content']}")
```

Comment: is update() pre defined function ??

Comment: if you are using getbuilder i usually use getbuilder so i always try to call update for some heavy widgets i also update my answer above.

Comment: First solution worked. quote.value. Can you explain a bit more about it ??

Comment: As far as am using getx using the RxString is say observable so in the end it wont read as normal string so using value is the one more like stripping it to normal string so the thing you gonna look at or put data also a string so the both data will be match e.g.  RxString == String is false but if you add RxString.value == String is true more something like that